# Dynamically changes the sequence (Order) of controls added in table td

Tags: angular, sorting, html-table

I already have a table (primeng) with different controls like datepicker, textbox, dropdown with different header.

Now I got the requirement to re-arrange those controls in a required sequence based on user choice.

[image]

If it is just a text then I could have done it with foreach loop of sorted data but how can I do that with already placed controls in the HTML file ?

Comment: if you need to change the order of the columns, seems like you'll need to branch on *ngIf statements (or ngSwitch/Case?)...  You'd probably have a different <table> for each case so a lot of duplicated markup.